# Maven WebApp tomcat7 system properties

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, system-properties

We are using a maven dependency to add embedded tomcat on our webapplication. It works fine, but I need to add systemProperties to embedded tomcat, so that our webapp can use this systemProperties.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tomcat-run</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/html5</path>
                        <enableNaming>true</enableNaming>
                        <finalName>html5.jar</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried to add system properties like this, but it didn't work. I added it

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <dashboard.oracle.host>1.1.1.1</dashboard.oracle.host>
                    <dashboard.oracle.port>1521</dashboard.oracle.port>
                    <dashboard.oracle.sid>orcl</dashboard.oracle.sid>
                    <dashboard.oracle.url>
                        jdbc:oracle:thin:@${dashboard.oracle.host}:${dashboard.oracle.port}:${dashboard.oracle.sid}
                    </dashboard.oracle.url>
                    <dashboard.oracle.username>username</dashboard.oracle.username>
                    <dashboard.oracle.password>password</dashboard.oracle.password>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            ...
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 7):

In general the way you have added the system properties to the tomcat plugin is correct:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <systemProperties>
      <example.value.1>alpha</example.value.1>
      <example.value.2>beta</example.value.2>
    </systemProperties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Taken from the [Apache Docu](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat6-maven-plugin/examples/add-system-properties.html).

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve these properties from a separate file? In the example given, the developers likely do not want to put username and password in source control.

Answer (score 2):

the system properties in the Maven Plugin are only for when running the tomcat7:run mojo ... in order to pass in the system properties to the executable war (jar), you must do it on the command line:
java -DsysProp1=value -DsysProp2=value -jar exec-war.jar